# How to keep serial port open when being used as a method

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have a method which opens a serial port, reads some data into an array, and then closes the port again. This method can be called up to 20 times per second but I feel this may be ineffective.

The method can be called from multiple windows forms and locations.

```
class COMPortStream
    {
        private static readonly string COM = Properties.Settings.Default.COMPort;
        public static SerialPort ForcePort = new SerialPort(COM, 19200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
        public double N2P(double N)
        {
            double lbf = N * 0.224809;
            return lbf;
        }
        public string[] GetLoads()
        {

            try
            {
                if (!ForcePort.IsOpen) { ForcePort.Open(); }
                string buffer = ForcePort.ReadTo("\r") ;
                string message = ForcePort.ReadTo("\r");
                string[] arr = message.Split('N');
                ForcePort.Close();

                for( int i =0;i<2;i++)
                {
                    double ld = N2P(Convert.ToDouble(arr[i]));
                    arr[i] = ld.ToString("N1");
                }
                return arr;

            }

            catch (TimeoutException)
            {
                ForcePort.Close();
                return null;
            }
            catch(InvalidOperationException ex)
            {

                ForcePort.Close();
                return null;
            }
            catch(SystemException)
            {
                ForcePort.Close();
                return null;
            }
        }
```

The above works but I feel it is inefficient. What I would like is a method / function which is continually reading the stream regardless of which form is showing - almost like a background worker for the entire program. This would save the numbers into a public array and other forms/functions would query this instead.

Comment: Why not make the class IDisposable, then close the port when it is disposed. No need to make the port object static, no need to close after each read, just open it once.

Comment: Open the port in a more global context.  Have the methods assume it is open.

Comment: You need to make your class accept a `SerialPort` and you just pass it the same serialport each time it's called (no matter where its called).  `public string[] GetLoads(SerialPort ForcePort)`  You'll have to figure out where you want to close the port and open it.